# Learning DLR (how to implement a language on top of it)

Tags: c#, dynamic-language-runtime, dynamic-languages

I am trying to learn how to write a simple scripting language on top of DLR, by playing with a very old DLR example called ToyScript. However ToyScript does not seem to support the following structure of a script, which I would like to use in my implementation :

```
print b()
def b() { 
  return 1 
}
```

It raises an exception, exactly as in most statically compiled languages.'

If the script follows a "static languages paradigm" :

```
def b() { 
  return 1 
}
print b()
```

ToyScript works without problems.

My question is : how the former should be done in DLR ?

[Obviously I am looking for a description of a solution, and not for a solution itself :)]

Comment: Regarding "as in most statically compiled languages": I don't know that, but I do know that you would get an error executing the first block in many *dynamic* languages too (JavaScript, Python and Ruby, just to name a few).

Comment: I just had a look over [IronPython](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#IronPython_Main/) but it seems a lot of work to implement it. You might want to look at how they did it and go trial&error.

Comment: You'll have to make a much smarter interpreter.  It needs to make *two* passes through that code.  The first pass must add definitions, the second pass executes code.  The way static compilers do it :)

Comment: a script is usually interpreted top to bottom. the call to b therefore cannot be before the declaration.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few possible implementations. The first is to require an execution to create a function. With this way, you cannot invoke a function before a function is created with an execution. The second way is to create the all the functions when you parse the code and execute the global scripts. With this way, function declaration can appear anywhere in the code because the functions are already created before any execution. The draw back is that you need to create all the functions no matter you invoke them or not. Then there is an in-between way; when you parse the code for the first time, you store the abstract syntax tree (AST) of the functions in a function table. Then when you want to invoke a function, look for the function declaration in the function table and then compile or interpret from the AST. Compare the following two JavaScript snippets and you will have a good idea.

```
console.log(b());
function b() {
    return 1;
}
```

and

```
console.log(b());
var b = function() {
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for a sugestion, but I feel there must be a simpler solution available :). Consider a 'dynamic' keyword in C#. You can call unkown members on an object and a proper binding is done during a runtime. Although I am not a compiler expert at all, I guess something logically similar could be utilised to achive my goals here :).